# Why would I want to use yii-strap and not just plain bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I want to make a site using yii, I also want to incorporate twitter bootstrap. Why would I use yii strap over just importing and using bootstrap manually? I have looked on the site but there seems to be no information as to why you would need to use yii-strap.

Comment: In simple words, to speed up your development time. You won't need to write markup to add bootstrap button it's more easy with yii-strap or any other extension. for example to make a button: TbHtml::button("learn more...");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii-strap is a back-end integration of Bootstrap. Typically with a back-end MVC framework you don't write pure HTML templates. You use your back-end language to write code that generates the HTML files.

Take the Components examples: http://www.getyiistrap.com/site/components

Here you see that Bootstrap is integrated via PHP statements, and not HTML:

```
<?php echo TbHtml::buttonToolbar(array(
    array('items' => array(
        array('label' => '1'),
        array('label' => '2'),
        array('label' => '3'),
        array('label' => '4'),
    )),
    array('items' => array(
        array('label' => '5'),
        array('label' => '6'),
        array('label' => '7'),
    )),
    array('items' => array(
        array('label' => '8'),
    )),
)); ?>
```

This wouldn't be possible with native Bootstrap--methods like `buttonToolbar()` wouldn't exist.